# Express 4 — how to parse signed cookies?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, authorization

I'm doing authorisation with Socket.IO and Express 4. As Express.JS no more relies on Connect middleware, I've got a problem parsing signed cookies string  with new [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) module. Let's say I need check session in RedisStore by cookies. Here's what I've got from Socket.IO handshakeData:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8081',
  accept: '*/*',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  cookie: 'io=CyMFrlbrFD23UeVbAAAA; connect.sid=s%3ADHWS7fJ8e5mQ35yvrKwUBQXH7oAIoEIz.R0TLqQ93IwotvIxNqdU17IgPDKOBMXnlM9eTZ8e4gFU',
  ...
}
```

How to parse `cookie` parameter with sessionSecret I have to search for suitable session in Redis store?

Previously I used

```
sessionID = globals.connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshakeData.cookie["connect.sid"], SESSON_SECRET)
```

and searched in Redis by key with

```
client.get "sess:" + String(sessionID), (err, reply) ->
  ... # we found session object with username, success!
```

Now I can't do this trick.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was simple:

```
cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
handshakeData.sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie( handshakeData.cookie["connect.sid"], globals.config.express.sessionSecret )
```